# Spark Streaming : Write to PSQL Table from Kafka

Tags: postgresql, scala, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

What is the correct way to write DStream data from Kafka using Spark-Streaming to an SQL table like Postgres?

For ex. I would have this,

```
 val directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[..]
```

Using forEachRDD, I will map the data to a case class. And, do something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = id_from_kafka_rdd;
```

And, then with the result from this, I will do some other comparisons and decide whether to update the Postgres table with data from Kafka. In effect, I might have to do operations like INSERT, UPDATE etc on the Postgres table.

What is the correct way to do this? Spark SQL, DataFrames or the JDBC connector method? I am a beginner to Spark.

Thanks in advance.